# Any intelligence to run the Azure Data Factory other than Schedule Basis

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-data-factory

I have a Client Request for my Data Factory Solution

They want to run my Data-Factory when ever the i/p file is available in the Blob Storage/any location.To be very clear they doesn't want to run the solution in an schedule basis,because some day the file won't shows up.So **i want an intelligence to search whether the file is available to be process in the location or not.If yes then i have to run my Data factory Solution to process that file,else no need to run the Data factor**

Thanks in Advance

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've currently got 3 options to dealing with this. None of which are exactly what you want...

**Option 1** - use C# to create a custom activity that does some sort of checking on the directory before proceeding with other downstream pipelines.

**Option 2** - Add a long delay to the activity so the processing retires for the next X days. Sadly only a maximum of 10 long retires is allowed currently.

**Option 3** - Wait for a newer version of Azure Data Factory that might allow the possibility of more event driven activities, rather than using a scheduled time slice approach.

Apologies this isn't exactly the answer you want. But this gives you current options.

Comment: Is there is any alerts for whenever the file gets uploaded in the blob container it has to trigger a event or something like that ?
Currently i'm seeing the alerts for Storage account for the Metric changes in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-monitor-storage-account

Comment: Those alerts can't currently be used to trigger an event in Azure Data Factory. You only have time slice schedules available, not event driven handling.

Comment: Thanks Paul.! Is there is any assurance,if Microsoft Update this feature in the Newer Version of Azure Data Factory ?

Comment: I don't know. I've just heard rumours and passed by feedback to various people in the product group.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I marked this as an answer.Any way you gave the available options for me.Could you please accept my Connect request in Likedin,i would love to connect with you